# Android - If condition is not working correctly

Tags: java, android, string, if-statement

Can any please find out what is the mistake I am doing here... 
The value in str is printing true everywhere but still it goes to else..
Thanks in Advance

```
         String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("gotit signup response from web", str);


        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {

            // GO TO HOMEPAGE
            Intent j = new Intent();
            j.setClassName("com.test.babynames", "com.test.babynames.Home");
           startActivity(j);


        }else
        {
            Log.w("gotit Signup .... ",str);
            Log.w("gotit Signup .... ", "FALSE");
            result.setText(str);                
        }
```

Comment: why are you doing this: `str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(` instead of `str.equalsIgnoreCase(`  ?

Comment: `str` is already a string, why use the `.toString()` method?  Does `str` have spaces around it?  @Kimi This http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html says String.toString() returns the string itself.

Comment: You should do a trim on it, just to be sure there is not spaces after your 'true' value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because it contains a space or another invisible character. Try printing it enclosed in delimiters, and/or use the `trim()` method to remove whitespace chars at the beginning and the end of the string.

If this still doesn't work, print the numeric value of every character of the string, and do the same with "true", to detect where they differ:

```
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    System.out.println((int) c);
}
```

And calling toString() on a String doesn't make any sense, as said in the comments. The String class overrides `Object.toString()` to return itself.